# Rasperry Pi: cvlc "Floating point exception"

Tags: stream, vlc, rtsp, raspbian

I'm trying to channel a rtsp stream to a flv stream to be able to show it in a browser using vlc.
I'm using the following command:

```
cvlc rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx :sout='#transcode{vcodec=FLV1,scale=1,acodec=none,deinterlace}:http{mime=video/x-flv,mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=127.0.0.1:8090/device_1.flv}' :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=5 :sout-keep :no-audio --video --no-sout-audio
```

After using it the following output is generated:

```
VLC media player 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax) (revision 2.2.1-0-ga425c42)
[0027f898] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[001e68f8] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0027f900] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0027f900] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[001e68f8] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0027f8d8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[6fc017e8] access_output_http access out: Consider passing --http-host=IP on the command line instead.
[6fb00508] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[6fb00508] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
MultiFramedRTPSource::doGetNextFrame1(): The total received frame size exceeds the client's buffer size (100000).  53926 bytes of trailing data will be dropped!
[h264 @ 0x6f907600] corrupted macroblock 3 43 (total_coeff=-1)
[h264 @ 0x6f907600] error while decoding MB 3 43
Floating point exception
```

I have no experience with vlc so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue recently. The following solution is not exactly solving vlc issue, but it allows me to stream video over raspbian eventually.

## Raspi stream with UV4L

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following lines to the file

```
# for uv4l library
deb http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/ jessie main
# for old version libssl1.0.0 lib that is a dependency for uv4l-server
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

Update package list and install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install uv4l uv4l-raspicam uv4l-raspicam-extras uv4l-webrtc
```

Edit default configs optionally, I.e setting up ssl, or encoding format etc...

```
sudo vim /etc/uv4l/uv4l-raspicam.conf
```

Finally, start service that will host the server on raspberry pi

```
sudo service uv4l_raspicam start # stop
```

Navigate to

```
http://raspberryAddress:8080/
```

and you should see the UI.